# How to write negative relationship condition in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I write a Cypher statment:

```
match p=(:Fabric)-[:Child*]-(f:Fabric{code:'PC16-18121'})-[:Child*]-(ef:Fabric)
match (ef)-[:Refrence]-(r:RequestOrder)
return p,r
```

**Result:**
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWOWe.png)

But I want another result:
[Don't display the node that without ‘result’ relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6y5Eu.png)

**Question:**

How to write this in Cypher?

Comment: The term ‘CQL’ is more commonly used for the Cassandra Query Language, so please use ‘Cypher’ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a pattern predicate to indicate you only want :RequestOrders without :Result relationships.

Also, we can clean up that query a bit, currently it's matching down :Child* relationships to :Fabrics twice.

```
match p=(:Fabric{code:'PC16-18121'})-[:Child*]-(:Fabric)-[:Refrence]-(r:RequestOrder) 
where not (r)-[:Result]-()
return p,r
```

You may also want to correct the spelling of :Reference in your graph.

EDIT: to get the path to all :FABRIC nodes as well, try this:

```
match p=(:Fabric{code:'PC16-18121'})-[:Child*]-(f:Fabric)
optional match (f)-[:Refrence]-(r:RequestOrder)
where not (r)-[:Result]-()
return p,r
```

Comment: Edited my answer, it should match your desired result.

Comment: Perfect!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of InverseFalcon's example I know what to do:

```
match (f:Fabric{code:'PC16-18121'}),
(f)-[:Child*]->(:Fabric)-[:Refrence]-(r:RequestOrder)
where not (r)-[:Result]-()
return (f)-[:Child*]->(:Fabric),(:Fabric)-[:Child*]->(f),
(f)-[:Child*]->(:Fabric)-[:Refrence]-(r:RequestOrder)
```

**Result is:**  [Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE8fM.png)

Thank you @InverseFalcon

Comment: Keep in mind that this kind of return is likely doing a lot more work than is needed. Try running a PROFILE on the query.